# Why is this function returning NaN?

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, date, nan

At first this might seem to be like many of the other questions already asked regarding NaN in JavaScript, but I assure you it's not.

I have this piece of code that converts grabs the value from a textbox, and converts it into a date after clicking a button in a form:

```
var dateString = $('#itemAcquiredTxt').val(); //Would have a value of '2013-12-15'
var dateAcquired = new Date(dateString); //Invalid Date ?
```

The textbox itemAcquiredTxt would have a value of "2013-12-15" (YYYY-MM-DD format) taken from a database call:

```
$('#itemAcquiredTxt').val(new Date(item.DateAcquired).toLocaleDateString());
```

After creating the new Date object it gives me "Invalid Date".

OK... So I thought of making the Date object by passing it year, month and day as numbers - one of its other constructors.

```
 var year = Number(dateString.split("-")[0]); //Returns NaN
 var month = Number(dateString.split("-")[1]); //Returns NaN
 var day = Number(dateString.split("-")[2]); //Returns NaN
 var dateAcquired = new Date(year, month - 1, day); //InvalidDate
```

I tried splitting the string in the date textbox by the dash, and convert the string into a number using both Number and parseInt - but both gave me a NaN. I double checked the string values and nothing seemed wrong: "2013", "12", "15" on the split items respectively.

I said to myself...maybe my code is bad, and tried it on JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/jrxg40js/
But as you can see there, after placing a date in the text and pressing the button, it works!

Heres the relevant HTML code

```
<table id="inputTable">
            <tr>
                <td><span><strong>Name:</strong></span></td>
                <td><input id="itemNameTxt" type="text" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span><strong>Category:</strong></span></td>
                <td>
                    <select id="categorySelect" ng-model="selectedCategory" ng-change="changeSubCategoryList(selectedCategory)" ng-options="cat as cat.CategoryName for cat in categoriesObj track by cat.CategoryID">
                        <option value="">---Please Select One---</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-show="hasSubCat">
                <td><span><strong>Sub Category</strong></span></td>
                <td>
                    <select id="subCategorySelect">
                        <option value="">---Please Select One---</option>
                        <option ng-repeat="sub in subCategoryObj" value="{{sub.SubCatID}}">{{sub.SubCatName}}</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span><strong>Description:</strong></span></td>
                <td><input id="itemDescriptionTxt" type="text" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span><strong>Serial Number:</strong></span></td>
                <td><input id="itemSerialNumberTxt" type="text" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span><strong>Year:</strong></span></td>
                <td><input id="itemYearTxt" type="text" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span><strong>Initial Cost:</strong></span></td>
                <td><input id="itemValueTxt" type="text" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span><strong>Department:</strong></span></td>
                <td>
                    <select id="departmentSelect">
                        <option value="">---Please Select One---</option>
                        <option ng-repeat="dep in departmentsObj" value="{{dep.RoleID}}">{{dep.RoleDescription}}</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span><strong>Campus:</strong></span></td>
                <td>
                    <select id="campusSelect" ng-model="selectedCampus" ng-change="changeBuildingList(selectedCampus)" ng-options="campus as campus.CampusDescription for campus in campusesObj track by campus.CampusID">
                        <option value="">---Please Select One---</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span><strong>Building:</strong></span></td>
                <td>
                    <select id="buildingSelect">
                        <option value=""> </option>
                        <option ng-repeat="building in buildingsObj" value="{{building.BuildingID}}">{{building.BuildingDescription}}</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span><strong>Date Acquired:</strong></span></td>
                <td><input id="itemAcquiredTxt" type="text" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span><strong>Notes:</strong></span></td>
                <td>
                    <textarea id="noteTxt"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Relevant AngularJS function used to update the item with new data keyed by user - the function gets called when a user presses a confirmation button:

```
$scope.editItem = function () {
    var dateString = $('#itemAcquiredTxt').val();
    dateAcquired = new Date(dateString);
    var invItem = {
        ItemID: $('#itemID').val(),
        ItemName: $('#itemNameTxt').val().trim(),
        CategoryID: $('#categorySelect').find(":selected").val(),
        SubCategoryID: $('#subCategorySelect').find(":selected").val(),
        Description: $('#itemDescriptionTxt').val().trim(),
        SerialNumber: $('#itemSerialNumberTxt').val().trim(),
        Year: $('#itemYearTxt').val().trim(),
        DateAcquired: dateAcquired,
        Value: $('#itemValueTxt').val().trim(),
        RoleID: $('#departmentSelect').find(":selected").val(),
        Barcode: null,
        Notes: $('#noteTxt').val().trim(),
        Deleted: null,
        AddedBy: null,
        DateAdded: null,
        ModifiedBy: null, //Added by server
        DateModified: null,
        DeletedBy: '',
        DateDeleted: null,
        CampusID: $('#campusSelect').find(":selected").val(),
        BuildingID: $('#buildingSelect').find(":selected").val(),
        RoomID: null
    };
    $http.put("api/inventory/", invItem).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        inventoryData.retrieveData(); //On success, refresh zeh data
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    $("#dialogForm").dialog("close");
```

Why is my code returning NaN on my working environment (Visual Studio 2015 debugging on IE11) when other sites, such as JSFiddle is returning what I'm expecting?

Comment: How certain are you that the date string really is exactly what you think it is? Have you used `console.log()` to dump it out to the console before using it to make a date, or checking via the browser debugger? It must be the case that something isn't happening the way you think it is. Verify all your assumptions!

Comment: For example: are you certain that there's only one `<input>` with that id on the page?

Comment: Pretty certain. Checked both browser debugger and console.log.
And yes, there's only one input with that id.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant HTML code? We won't be able to help you without knowing what `#itemAcquiredTxt` looks like.

Comment: `itemAcquiredTxt` is something else.

Comment: [Another fiddle using the posted HTML.](http://jsfiddle.net/bo8wzc8c/) This works fine. Exactly how is that code being called in your actual site?

Comment: Seems like a Microsoft problem with Visual Studio 2015.. but @Pointy is right see if you get the same `console.log` results in your browser and in Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Code is called via an AngularJS function inside a controller - 
a simple $scope.updateItem = function() that gets called when someone presses a button.

Comment: Looks like you're using Angular, maybe you should set a `ng-model="date_acquired"` on that field and grab it via `$scope.date_acquired`.

Comment: @David I tried that and still got InvalidDate.
Not sure why it's not converting it...

Comment: just to be very precise about it: `var dateString = $('#itemAcquiredTxt').val(); console.log(dateString);` writes a seemingly valid datestring even when using the configuration that 1 line down has the error?

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party JS libraries? What do you can when you execute console.log(Number) ?

Comment: reqarding the update....this shouldn't be a problem, but in light of how strange this error is...are you sure that the dateString from the DB has the right kind of dashes in it? you could compare the hex values of the DB string and a handwritten date

Comment: So the update to the field is made when someone presses the button. Are you trying to fetch the value before the ajax call has completed? The update to the field via the database access is almost certainly an asynchronous operation.

Comment: @cypherabe a ha! When I traverse through the string using the arrow keys, it stops at the dashes - I suspect it's a problem with the dashes when pulled from the DB.

*edit - Nope. Wasn't it

Comment: If you posted the code that involves that database update so that we can see how that relates to the code that attempts to build the Date, the problem might be obvious.

Comment: @Pointy The update happens when someone presses a button yes, but the value gets pre-populated at document load. User can't make any changes until all the data has been succesfully loaded so I don't believe that is the case.

edit- posted the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem - which really I have no idea what it even was.

The problem happened only during an update of the item, not while adding a new one - so it had to come when I was populating the element value.

```
$('#itemAcquiredTxt').val(new Date(item.DateAcquired).toLocaleDateString());
```

Doing a `console.log(item.DateAcquired)` returned a string "2015-12-15T00:00:00", the .toLocaleDateString() would convert it to "2015-12-15" and parsed into a Date object.

Editing that element's value would always result in a NaN/InvalidDate when trying to convert it's string into a date.

My solution was...

```
$('#itemAcquiredTxt').val(item.DateAcquired.split('T')[0]);
```

Not use Date at all. 
Now it works.